# Mark the build result as Failed OR Successful

Tags: ant, build.xml, ant-contrib

I want to mark the build as successful when the file exist(when I mark ) OR failed when file does not exist (when I mark var name="build-result" value="FAILED" />).
I want to update build status after reading build-result OR by using "build.status" which I am updating depending on build-result as

```
<var name="build-result" value="SUCCEEDED" />
                <echo message="Sending mail status- ${build-result}"/>
                <propertyfile file="${build-status.file}">
                        <entry key="build.status" value="${build-result}" />
                </propertyfile>
```

Currently I am doing in the way:

```
       <isset variable="build-result" value="FAILED" />

   </condition>
 </fail>
```

But is giving the message as: BUILD FAILED
D:\projects\Self\AntExample\build.xml:51: isset doesn't support the "variable" attribute
which I want should be like "Build Failed as File Does not Exist"

Answer (score 1):

Always refer to the on line documentation. `<isset>` takes the parameter `property` and not `variable`. Ant doesn't have the concept of variables -- just properties. What the `<var/>` task does is that it allows you to change a property once it is set. You should not be using `<var>` except in rare circumstances. As it says on the `<var>` task's page: **In general, use of this task is DISCOURAGED, and the standard Ant Property should be used if possible.**

In fact, now that you have `<local/>` in the list of standard Ant tasks, I find that you no longer really need `<var/>`.

If you want to fail your build if a file does not exist, look at the `<available>` test:

```
<fail message="This build is an utter and complete failure".>
    <condition>
        <not>
            <available file="${result.file}" type="file"/>
        </not>
    </condition>
</fail>

<echo message="This build is a smashing success! We're so proud!"/>
```

The `<fail>` task will execute if the file `${result.file}` is not found. Otherwise, the `<echo>` message will print.

Comment: +1 The var task is not part of core ANT. See the ant-contrib documentation: http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html

Answer (score 0):

`<isset>` accepts only one attribute- `property` and checks whether the specified property has been **set** or not (i.e. has been provided a value, including *null*)

See [**HERE**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#isset) for `<isset>`

what you may use is `<equals>` which compares the values of two arguments:

```
<equals arg1="${build-result}" arg2="FAILED">
```

See [**HERE**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#equals) for `<equals>`

as you've mentioned: `I want to mark the build as successful when the file exist` you may also want to look at the `<available>` task,
`<available property="result" file="your_file_location" />`

See [**HERE**](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/available.html) for `<available>`